# How to find a restaurant serving Halal food in Munich

Tags: food-and-drink, munich, islam

I am heading off to Munich this Sunday and I will be staying there for a month. My office is at the Landsberger Street and my residence at Shwere-Reiter-Straße. Does anyone know how to find some halal food restaurants in the walking distance of these two places?

Comment: Your question is a perfectly reasonable one but it's being downvoted because it's not a good fit for this site. Restaurants come and go, so answers are likely to go out of date quickly.

Comment: While this seems to be a basic 'google it' question, it turns out to be way less easy due to the location of the residence in the area.

Answer (score 4):

Halal food is fairly easy to get in Germany both in restaurants and in grocery stores. There are a lot of take out places that have halal options, some of which may be too small to have a website or pop up on google.

It's probably easiest if you ask/look/walk around when you are on the ground. You can look up a few places on Google (with maps) to get you around the first few days until you understand the local environment. Store directions to theses places and if they are outside walking distance you can take public transportation or ride share.

Some options close to Schwere Reiter Str. 
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Royem+Imbiss/@48.1617401,11.5570526,17z/data=!4m22!1m16!4m15!1m6!1m2!1s0x479e76744bc810cd:0xece331ec40f4f428!2sSchwere-Reiter-Stra%C3%9Fe,+M%C3%BCnchen,+Germany!2m2!1d11.5547032!2d48.1613623!1m6!1m2!1s0x479e75d914012dad:0xee38fb76d6739d25!2sRoyem+Imbiss,+Schlei%C3%9Fheimer+Str.+127,+80797+M%C3%BCnchen,+Germany!2m2!1d11.5636096!2d48.1626234!3e2!3m4!1s0x479e75d914012dad:0xee38fb76d6739d25!8m2!3d48.1626234!4d11.5636096

https://xn--alshaam-mnchen-osb.de/

Comment: It might be worth adding that (small) places with Halal food likely have this written outside on the window.

Answer (score 3):

Having run an internet search I did find a lot of restaurants in Munich that have a halal mention to their information.
The price range goes from very cheap to rather expensive.

When you are in Munich you best run a search on internet, if you are willing to have your location known to the search engine it will give local information, which is much better than what people from farther away can find. And do not restrict yourself to one search engine only, there are several which specialize in restaurants and there might be some places where you find Muslims share information.
Also talk with people in your place of work, whether they work for the same company or for an other, whether they would go for halal out of religious reasons or may just like the food that is often served in halal restaurents.
And the same goes for people you meet near where you stay.

I have run a search for you, not very successful, but I still share the results here with you.
Landsberger Strase is rather long and while there is a cluster of restaurants near one end of the street, there is no way to say whether they will be near your place of work. But many of the halal places to eat I am familiar with do deliver so that might be of help.

Your place of residence seems some way away from the part of town with most restaurants. But remember that many of the smaller halal places do not show up on internet maps, being more for the locals.
I could not find any within walking distance but that might be my distance from Munich, where a local search shows up more local results.
And also for dinner at home restaurants are often willing to deliver.

[Trip-advisor](https://en.tripadvisor.com.hk/Restaurants-g187309-oa30-zfz10751-Munich_Upper_Bavaria_Bavaria.html) has a good listing for when you want to go out for a good dinner.